# Open an Excel sheet from PowerPoint

Tags: excel, ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I am using `Office 2010` and I want to open a specific Excel from a PowerPoint slide. The PowerPoint slide should look the following:

On the slide I have an object or a link and when I click on that, the desired Excel sheet opens.

I tried to open it via the option: `Insert>Object>Microsoft Excel Worksheet` this basically gives me a new Excel sheet.

Any recommendations how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Insert>Object>Create from file` browse your file and tick the `Display as icon` box (FYI: Display as icon isn't available to be clicked until you have selected a file)